# inherit from std::function, syntax and usage?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, c++11, functor

I don't understand the syntax when a functor inherits from std::function:

```
class do_sth : public function< any_type (another_type) >
{
    bool operator() (string s) {...}
};
```

What should I use as any_type and another_type? And can you give me an example of a beneficial usage of inheriting from std::function since I haven't understood it yet?

Comment: Don't inherit from `std::function`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, why? absence of virtual destructor or something deeper?

Comment: @alfC `std::function` is a value type. It's usually not a good idea to inherit from value types. Lack of virtual destructor and lack of slicing protection are the concrete problems, but it's more of a philosophical issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the return type of your `operator ()` for `any_type` and the argument types for `another_type`. Then at least it fits.

But really, `std::function` is not meant to be inherited from, and doing so is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Well I still don't know in which case it would have a benefit... I mean I'm glad to hear that I don't need to use this but it was told us at university (to use it, not why...), so it must have any sense, doesn't it?

Comment: @LPrulzcrossover Given what I heard of some universities, no.